# Edit space for overbraces in equation

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations

I would like to use `\overbrace`s and `\underbrace`s in my equation. However, when I make the text for `\overbrace`s too long, the `\overbrace` doesn't contain the correct part.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\rlap{$\overbrace{\phantom{(r+\epsilon)V_t}}^{\text{Required return}}$} (r+\epsilon)V_t
=
\rlap{$\overbrace{\phantom{V_{t+1}^e-V_t}}^{\text{Expected capital gain}}$}\underbrace{D^e_t+V_{t+1}^e-V_t}_{\text{Total expected return on shares}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \overbrace{(r+\epsilon)V_t}^{\text{\clap{Required return}}}
  \quad = \quad \underbrace{\overbrace{D^e_t+V_{t+1}^e}^{\text{\clap{Expected capital gain}}}
              - V_t}_{\text{\clap{Total expected return on shares}}}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]